# Loading data into a 3D texture in Metal

Tags: ios, textures, metal

From what I understood by reading the docs, a 3D texture only has 1 slice. When I try to load data into it though, it fails with error:

```
MTLTexture.m:504: failed assertion `imageBytes(0) must be >= (2048).'
```

The code used to load is (texture is type `MTLPixelFormatRG16Uint` and size `elementsInRow * elementsInRow * elementsInRow`):

```
[texture replaceRegion:region mipmapLevel:0 withBytes:data bytesPerRow:sizeof(uint16_t) * 2 * elementsInRow];
```

where `elementsInRow` is `128`, region is `MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake3D(50, 50, 50, 4, 4, 4);` and data is `uint16_t data[region.size.depth][region.size.height][region.size.width][2]`.

I also tried with:

```
[texture replaceRegion:region mipmapLevel:0 slice:0 data bytesPerRow:sizeof(uint16_t) * 2 * elementsInRow bytesPerImage:sizeof(uint16_t) * 2 * elementsInRow * elementsInRow];
```

but it results in a memory error.

See also here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/43332#43332

**How can I correctly load data in a 3D region of a 3D texture?**

**UPDATE 1:**

The second example works when the region has depth `1` and even bigger `width` and `height` (but with `32x32x1` it will crash).

**UPDATE 2:**

If I use `16x16x1` and write the same value for every pixel in the region, it seems to work, but when I export the data as an image, it looks like random data is being written instead, see this zoomed section of the image:

[image]

If I run the test again, the image will have the same top section in uniform color, but the rest of the points will change intensity. Notice that I am writing the same value to every pixel, so the region should just be of uniform color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was it. I was trying to read from outside of boundaries memory, as the `bytesPerRow` and `bytesPerImage` parameters were not correct.

The documentation says:

> bytesPerRow
> For an ordinary or packed pixel format, the stride, in bytes, between rows of **source** data.
>
> bytesPerImage
> The stride, in bytes, between images in the **source** data.

I was passing the values thinking that they were referred to the *texture*, not the *region*.

So the code should be:

```
[texture replaceRegion:region mipmapLevel:0 slice:0 data bytesPerRow:sizeof(uint16_t) * 2 * region.size.width bytesPerImage:sizeof(uint16_t) * 2 * region.size.width * region.size.height];
```

You can never read the documentation carefully enough.